# Twitter API - Getting the retweet count of an account

Tags: php, json, twitter

I am looking to pull the total number of retweets a particular user has ever received. Is that possible?

Right now, I am able to pull the total tweet count, the number of followers and the number of friends.

The code I am working with is:

```
$username = "username";
$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json";
$requestMethod = "GET";
$getfield = "?screen_name=".$username."&include_entities=true";
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$string = json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
    ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
    ->performRequest(),$assoc = TRUE);
```

Answer (score 5):

The total number of retweets is not a property associated to the [Users](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/user-object). Each individual [Tweet](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/tweet-object) has the number of retweets it received in the field retweet_count.

You will need to get all the tweets of a user and add up the retweets to get the total retweets a user received. The problem you will find is that you are limited on the number of tweets you can get of a user  to the last 3200 tweets https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline.html .

Comment: Hi cannt we use the retweets_of_me endpoint to get this info?

Comment: @Sonal you can get the `Tweets authored by the authenticating user that have been retweeted by others` with that endpoint, I think that the original question wanted that data for any user.

Comment: Active link: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline.html